# How to open modal from anywhere in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ref

I have a modal when opened, display auth user data, currently, I can only open the modal on the dashboard, but I want to be able to render it from anywhere in my application. How do I achieve this?

**Dashboard**

```
     const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

     const trigerModal = ()=>(
       <ModalCustom visible={visible} setVisible={setVisible}>
            <form>
                <>
                  <h3>Select an Account</h3>
                  <ul className="account">
                      {accounts && accounts.map((item, i) => (
                        <li key={item.id}>
                          <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                          <h3>{item.email}</h3>         
                          <h3> {item.phone}</h3>
                        </li>            
                      ))}
                    </ul> 
                  <br />    
                </>  
             
            </form>
          </ModalCustom>
         
      )


return(
<div>
   {trigerModal()}
    <button onClick={()=> setVisible(true)}>Open modal</button
</div>

)
```

**Profile**

how do trigger the modal from this component

Answer (score 4):

Two statements will answer virtually every react question:

1. Don't mutate state (not applicable here)
2. Lift state up (this is the answer to your question).

Create a context - wrap your application in it, and have any component `useContext` to open a modal with whatever components you want it in:

```
export const ModalContext = React.createContext();

const ModalProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [modalContent,setModalContent] = useState();

  return (
     <ModalContext.Provider value={
       useMemo(() => ({
        hide:() => setModalContent(),
        open:setModalContent
       }),[]
     }>
       {modalContent ? <Modal>{modalContent}</Modal> : null}
       {children}
     </ModalContext.Provider>
  )  
}
```

Wrap you application in the `ModalProvider` component so the context will be available to all your components:

```
const AdminDashboard = () => (
   <ModalProvider>
    <OtherComponents/>
   </ModalProvider>
)
```

`SomeLink`, a component that is anywhere inside `AdminDashboard` can use `React.useContext` to access the state in `ModalProvider`

```
const SomeLink = () => {
   const { open } = React.useContext(ModalContext);

   return (
     <button onClick={() => open(<SomeModalContent/>)}>Click to Open!</button>
   )

}
```

Comment: Is it best practice to store jsx in the context?

Comment: @YedidyaRashi you can store whatever you want in context/state if it suits your needs. It’s not directly serializable, so if your app requires you to persist this type of state to a storage then I guess it wouldn’t work for you (if that’s what you meant).

Comment: Is there a way to check if the modal is open or closed?

Comment: you shouldn't dispatch update the jsx element into useState because it can be affect to performance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it from anywhere You need to use Global State (like Redux or Mobx)

If you want to control this  from parent component you can use `useRef`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most "react"-like solution but I don't like to solve everything "react"-like so here is how I solved it for my specific usecase.

1. Create a class with static access.
2. Place the modal high / outside the dom tree
3. set the necessary access in the modal component

**HelperClass**

```
export class ModalHelper {
    private static openFunction: (state: boolean) => void;
    public static setOpenFunction(f: (state: boolean) => void) {
        ModalHelper.openFunction = f;
    }
    public static setOpen(state: boolean) {
        if (ModalHelper.openFunction) {
            ModalHelper.openFunction(state);
        } else {
            console.error("ModalHelper called before setOpenFunction")
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Modal component**

```
export function ExplainerModal() {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        ModalHelper.setOpenFunction(setOpen);
        return () => {
            ModalHelper.setOpenFunction(undefined);
        };
    }, []);

    return <>I'm a modal</>
}
```

**Call from anywhere**

```
ModalHelper.setOpen(true);
```

Now keep in mind this only works for one modal, but can of course be further adapted to handle multiple modals (e.g. by adding a dict for the functions etc.)